# Android Backbutton Pressed Return to Two Activities

Tags: android

This may sounds simple, but I am so bewildered by it. I have searched but not found any solution.

My question is: How to return to two activities when back button pressed?
Like this: let me say that I have activities A, B and C (A -> B -> C). What I want to achieve is when I am on activity C and press the back button, It should return me to activity A. When I am on B and press back, it should return me to A too.

It may be implemented into a project with many activities, so I assume that I don't need to set the class name of where to return, It should be recorded automatically by the android. How to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is calling startActivityForResult() from Activity B, so that on the callback of the created Activity C, the previous Activity B gets finished as well. The callback function is called onActivityResult(), and in that, you want to call finish().

Example:

ActivityB:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);

...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    this.finish();
}
```

ActivityC:

```
//do stuff
```

This way, when you press Back (or call finish()) in ActivityC, it will call back on ActivityB's onActivityResult() function, and it will end them both.

Comment: Yes, I'll try it. I'll return for a respon. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. I will do a further exploration in this method, thanks!

Comment: I am glad it works as you intended :) I don't like messing with the activity stack, so this solution circumvents that.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the onBackPressed method and sent an intent to the activity you want.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to send intent to the activity A
}
```

One thing, I'm not sure if this goes well with the activity stack but you can alway try.

Comment: I though of it too before, but it means that I have to put the activity class name in the intent, which I stated before that the app should record itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can finish activity B , when you are starting intent for activity C, then activity stack will have activity A, and when you press back on activity C, activity A will be displayed.

just override onBackPressed in Activity C, and finish() it.

Comment: you can do this, if you are don't require activity B to be in activity stack to be used again.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Activity that you want to go back to with a special flag (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) from your onBackButtonPressed which will skip/remove the other activities in between. This way you can go back from C to A.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

I think this is better than messing around with the finish() or starting activity for result when there is no result to return.

Answer (score 0):

***A --> B --> C***

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will launch a new intent for `Activity A` and clears all the other activities from Stack.